# Crawling websites that have SSO through OKTA

Tags: scrapy, web-crawler, okta

We host a website which authenticates the user using OKTA. We would like to crawl the website looking for broken links.

Is there a library/way to build a general purpose link checker that can crawl websites and point out broken links that works with an OKTA login?

I have used scrapy before, but dont see anything in the documentation specific to OKTA.

Answer (score 1):

We do not have recommendations for a specific web scraper that works with Okta. As far as we know, there exist no scrapers that work with SAML.